# What is the best way to load a UITableView inside of a UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

My haphazard attempt isn't calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` . I'm assuming my setup is not right.

```
let wordTableView        = WordTableView(frame: CGRectZero)
wordTableView.delegate   = self
wordTableView.dataSource = self
wordTableView.words      = words
let currentCell = wordTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.contentView.addSubview(wordTableView)
wordTableView.viewDidLoad()
wordTableView.reloadData()
```

When I run this, my UITableView's viewDidLoad() get's called. But nothing actually loads. If I look at the Debug View Hierarchy, I can see that nothing has been added. So I assume I'm missing something particular about instantiating this tableView.

For reference, this is my UITableView. But to be honest, I'm completely guessing about what exactly a UITableView would need to get instantiated. And this would be my best attempt :

```
class WordTableView: UITableView {

    var words = [Word]()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "WordCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordCell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordCell

        let word = words[indexPath.row]
        cell.sanskrit.text = "Sanskrit" //word.valueForKey("sanskrit")
        cell.definition.text = "Definition" // word.valueForKey("definition")

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Question - why are you putting a table view inside the cells of another table view? Wouldn't it be easier to simply section the main table view? And it's really confusing to put a method named `viewDidLoad` into a non-view controller class.

Comment: @rmaddy Yah, thanks for asking. It's a dynamic ordered list I'm trying to reveal. So previously, I was trying to do it with UILabels and UIViews, but because its all dynamic and mostly programmatic, it was turning into hell for my newb self, i thought.. why not just make a xib, and a UITableView to display a list. What do you think?

Comment: If I were you I'd simply add more rows and/or sections to the main table view. Nested table views can cause all kinds of problems with scrolling and touch events.

Comment: I actually went with your advice @rmaddy and that ended up being my solution. to use my existing tableview. if you wanted to somehow make that into an answer, i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You set `wordTableView` data source and delegate to the setter class, so table view data source and delegate function will not be called in `WordTableView` class.
Since you said your `viewDidLoad` is called, let set the delegate inside this function.

```
let wordTableView = WordTableView(frame: CGRectZero)
wordTableView.words = words
let currentCell = wordTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.contentView.addSubview(wordTableView)
wordTableView.viewDidLoad()
wordTableView.reloadData()
```

And `WordTableView` class

```
class WordTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var words = [Word]()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "WordCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordCell")
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordCell

        let word = words[indexPath.row]
        cell.sanskrit.text = "Sanskrit" //word.valueForKey("sanskrit")
        cell.definition.text = "Definition" // word.valueForKey("definition")

        return cell
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should not call `viewDidLoad()` directly and it is better if you make `WordTableView` inherit `UIViewController` and put your table view inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your viewDidLoad is being called because you are doing so explicitly, but your frame is CGRectZero, so it technically has no size, so there is nothing to add as a subView, so nothing gets called.

I think a better way to initialise the table view is to create your own initialiser, e.g.

```
class WordTableView: UITableView {

var words = [Word]()

init(frame: CGRect, wordArray: [Word], delegate: UITableViewDelegate, dataSource: UITableViewDataSource) {
    self.frame = frame
    words = wordArray
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.dataSource = dataSource 
    self.reloadData()
}

func viewDidLoad() {
    self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "WordCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordCell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return words.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordCell

    let word = words[indexPath.row]
    cell.sanskrit.text = "Sanskrit" //word.valueForKey("sanskrit")
    cell.definition.text = "Definition" // word.valueForKey("definition")

    return cell
}
```

}

And then in your setup:

```
let wordTableView = WordTableView(frame: cell.contentView.bounds, wordArray: words, delegate: self, dataSource: self)
let currentCell = wordTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.contentView.addSubview(wordTableView)
cell.setNeedsDisplay()
```